# Angular module dependencies - Clarification?

Tags: angularjs

I have an application which I declare as :

```
var app = angular.module('mg.app', ['mg.auth' , 'ui.router'  ,'mg.calc'  ]);
```

*`mg.auth` and `mg.calc` are modules (my modules) which I inject as   dependencies.*

**Code for `mg.auth`** :

```
angular.module('mg.auth', ['ui.router']);
angular.module('mg.auth').config(function ($stateProvider)
    {
        $stateProvider.state('signin', {
          ...
        });
    });
```

**Code for    `mg.calc`**:

```
angular.module('mg.calc', ['ui.router','ui.bootstrap']); 
angular.module('mg.calc').config(function ($stateProvider)
        {
            $stateProvider.state('calc', {
             ...
            });
        }
```

In the HTML I have :

```
 <a href ui-sref="calc">
```

When I click that link , it changes the state to `calc` and I do see the desired result.

*So where is the problem ?*

Looking at my *main* module (`ng.app`) , If I *remove* `mg.calc` as a dependecy there is an error :

[image]

But I don't understand **why** do I need 'mg.calc' as a depency of `mg.app` ?

I mean , When JS engine sees the code for `mg.calc` :

```
    angular.module('mg.calc', ['ui.router','ui.bootstrap']); 
    angular.module('mg.calc').config(function ($stateProvider)
            {
                $stateProvider.state('calc', {
                 ...
                });
            }
```

It knows that there is a new `calc` state and should be able to transit to calc.

**Question**

Functionallity , why do `mg.app` must set `mg.calc` as a dependency ?

**It is not that** I use some code from `mg.calc` in `mg.app`

Comment: Beacuse In the section of `ng-app` you have called `mg.app` so it will render only that module and its dependent module data.

Comment: @KunalKakkad "render" ?

Comment: render means 'will be effective'. I mean that the module which you have passed in `ng-app` will be effective and alongwith that its injected/dependent modules will be effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because your angular app was bootstrapped with mg.app module, not mg.calc module, that's why you need to tell angular that you need mg.calc as well.

Comment: So even if mg.app doesn't use a code from mg.calc - I still need to reference the module because mg.app is the entry point ?

Comment: you clicked on the link 'calc', that's when you used it. what happened was that ui-router was trying to find state configuration for 'calc' but couldn't find anything. that's why the error was thrown.

Comment: But the code for registration the route state - was executed !

Comment: yes, it was executed but the route state was registered in mg.calc module. If you don't inject mg.calc module into your main app module, how does your main module know about it?